"Violation - message handler took xxms" when rendering multiple Highcharts on the same page
I am using Next.js 14 along with Highcharts to render multiple charts on the same page.
Depending on the page, I may have between 3 to 5 charts displayed simultaneously. Although the data sets for the charts are not very complex, I am experiencing significant performance warnings, such as:
[Violation] 'message' handler took xxms
These warnings mainly occur when I switch between pages or when multiple charts are rendered at the same time.
Project Setup

Next.js 14 with App Router.
I use dynamic imports with ssr: false to lazily load the charts client-side.
Each type of chart (like line charts, bar charts, etc.) uses a common BaseChart component, where I pass the chart configurations.

Here is an overview of my setup:
BaseGraph.tsx
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import Highcharts, { type SeriesOptionsType } from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';
import AccessibilityModule from 'highcharts/modules/accessibility';
import useMessages from '@/services/hooks/useMessages';
import NoDataToDisplay from 'highcharts/modules/no-data-to-display';
import { ChartBreakPoints, ChartTypes } from '@/services/charts/ChartService';
import { Colors } from '@/utils/colors';
import HighchartsMap from 'highcharts/modules/map';
import { merge } from '@/utils/Highcharts';

interface BaseChartProps {
  chartType: string
  chartData: any
  chartOptions: Highcharts.Options
  isLoading: boolean
  setIsLoading: (isLoading: boolean) => void
  yAxisUnit?: string
  chartId: string
  title?: string
  isForHomePage?: boolean
}

export default function BaseChart ({
  chartType,
  chartData,
  isLoading,
  setIsLoading,
  chartOptions,
  yAxisUnit,
  chartId,
  title,
  isForHomePage = false
}: Readonly<BaseChartProps>): React.JSX.Element {
  const messages = useMessages();
  const chartRef = useRef<HighchartsReact.RefObject>(null);
  const chart = chartRef.current?.chart as any;

  useEffect(() => {
    NoDataToDisplay(Highcharts);
    AccessibilityModule(Highcharts);
    HighchartsMap(Highcharts);

    Highcharts.setOptions({
      lang: {
        noData: messages('charts.no-data-message'),
        decimalPoint: ','
      }
    });
  }, []);

  const commonOptions: Highcharts.Options = {
    chart: {
      type: chartType,
      animation: false,
    },
    noData: {
      style: {
        fontWeight: '600',
        fontSize: '16px',
        color: '#0D0D0D'
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      xDateFormat: '%d/%m/%Y',
      borderRadius: 8,
      shadow: {
        color: '#000000',
        opacity: 0.02,
        offsetX: 0,
        offsetY: 2,
        width: 10
      },
      shared: false,
      useHTML: true,
    },
    legend: {
      itemHoverStyle: {
        color: '#0D0D0D'
      },
      alignColumns: false,
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        events: {
          legendItemClick: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
          }
        },
        animation: false
      }
    },
 
    series: chartData as SeriesOptionsType[];
  };

  const finalOptions: Highcharts.Options = merge(commonOptions, chartOptions);

  return (
    <section id={chartId}>
      <HighchartsReact
        highcharts={Highcharts}
        options={finalOptions}
        ref={chartRef}
        constructorType={chartType === ChartTypes.MAP ? 'mapChart' : undefined}
      />
    </section>
  );
}

The BaseGraph is then used inside every type of graph, for exemple a line chart :
LineChart.tsx
'use client';
import React from 'react';
import type Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import LineChartTooltip from './LineChartTooltip';
import { type LineChartEvolDataType } from '@/services/charts/types/ChartDataTypes';
import { ChartTypes } from '@/services/charts/ChartService';
import LazyBaseChart from '@/components/charts/common/LazyBaseChart';

interface Props {
  lineChartData: LineChartEvolDataType
  yAxisUnit: string
  tooltipUnit?: string
  chartId: string
  isForHomePage?: boolean
  min?: number
  max?: number
  title?: string
  isLoading: boolean
  setIsLoading: (loading: boolean) => void
  numberDecimals?: number
}
export default function LineChart ({
  lineChartData,
  yAxisUnit,
  isForHomePage = false,
  numberDecimals,
  min,
  max,
  chartId,
  isLoading,
  tooltipUnit,
  setIsLoading,
  title
}: Readonly<Props>): React.JSX.Element {
  const options: Highcharts.Options = {
    tooltip: {
      shared: true,
      shape: 'rect',
      formatter ({ chart }) {
        const points = chart.hoverPoints;
        if (points?.[0].x) {
          const element = React.createElement(LineChartTooltip, {
            points,
            x: parseFloat(points[0]?.x.toString()),
            yAxisUnit: tooltipUnit ?? yAxisUnit,
            numberDecimals
          });
          return ReactDOMServer.renderToString(element);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <LazyBaseChart
      chartType={ChartTypes.LINE}
      chartData={lineChartData}
      isLoading={isLoading}
      setIsLoading={setIsLoading}
      chartOptions={options}
      chartId={chartId}
      yAxisUnit={yAxisUnit}
      title={title}
      isForHomePage={isForHomePage}
    />
  );
}

The LazyBaseChart is just the dynamic lazy loading form Nextjs used like this :
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import Loader from '@/components/theme/atoms/Loader';
import React from 'react';

const LazyBaseChart = dynamic(
  async () => await import('@/components/charts/common/BaseGraph'), {
    ssr: false,
    loading: () => <Loader />
  });

export default LazyBaseChart;


I tried to optimize the performance of my Highcharts implementation by removing animations and some Highcharts modules such as the noData and accessibility modules. Despite these efforts, I am still encountering the Violation - message handler took xxms warnings.
The warnings seem to appear primarily when multiple charts (between 3 to 5) are rendered on a single page. When only one chart is displayed, the warning does not appear.
I have trouble understanding why these warnings appear and what I can do to fix them, could you please provide any insights on the subject ?
Any assistance or recommendations for improving performance and resolving these warnings would be greatly appreciated.

I see that you're already using lazy loading and have removed animations from Highcharts. It looks a bit unusual, but as always, if you encounter any performance issues with Highcharts, please try using the Boost module, as it greatly improves performance: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/boost-module If it doesn't help please reproduce this issue in an online editor I could work on.
